# local variable vs instance variable Ruby initialize

Tags: ruby, initialization

I have a class in Ruby where I pass in a Hash of commodity prices. They are in the form

```
{"date (string)" => price (float), etc, etc}
```

and in the initialise method I convert the dates to Dates like so:

@data = change_key_format(dates)

But I notice that that method seems to change the original argument as well. Why is that? Here is the code:

```
def initialize(commodity_name, data)
    puts "creating ...#{commodity_name}"
    @commodity_name = commodity_name
    @data = change_hash_keys_to_dates(data)
    @dates = array_of_hash_keys(data)
    puts data ######## UNCHANGED
    @data = fix_bloomberg_dates(@data, @dates)
    puts data ######## CHANGED -------------------- WHY???
    #get_price_data
end


def fix_bloomberg_dates(data, dates)
    #Fixes the bad date from bloomberg  
    data.clone.each do |date, price|

        #Looks for obvious wrong date
        if date < Date.strptime("1900-01-01")
            puts dates[1].class
            date_gap = (dates[1] - dates[2]).to_i


            last_date_day = dates[1].strftime("%a %d %b")
            last_date_day = last_date_day.split(" ")
            last_date_day = last_date_day[0].downcase

            #Correct the data for either weekly or daily prices
            #Provided there are no weekend prices
            if date_gap == 7 && last_date_day == "fri"
                new_date = dates[1] + 7
                data[new_date] = data.delete(date)
            elsif date_gap == 1  && last_date_day == "thu"
                new_date = dates[1] + 4
                data[new_date] = data.delete(date)
            else
                new_date = dates[1] + 1
                data[new_date] = data.delete(date)
            end         
        end
    end

    return data
end

def change_hash_keys_to_dates(hash)
    hash.clone.each do |k,v|
        date = Date.strptime(k, "%Y-%m-%d")

        #Transforms the keys from strings to dates format
        hash[date] = hash.delete(k)
    end
    return hash
end

def array_of_hash_keys(hash)
    keys = hash.map do |date, price|
        date
    end
    return keys
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Because of these lines:

```
data[new_date] = data.delete(date)
```

You're modifying the original `data` object. If you don't want to do this, create a copy of the object:

```
data2 = data.clone
```

and then replace all other references to `data` with `data2` in your method (including `return data2`).

Comment: oh i see. I don't think I care if I'm modifying the original hash, should i?

Comment: I am surprised that it's doing that, I would have thought that the variable in the function would have been a copy

Comment: @ZachSmith Hmm, wait, are `@data` and `data` different variables? If so, 1.) That's a bit confusing, and 2.) You'll need to post your `change_hash_keys_to_dates` and `array_of_hash_keys` methods to further diagnose the problem.

Comment: I've added the other functions, though I still can't see why an argument of the initialize function is being transformed by another function if it's not an instance variable (@data is the instance variable, data is just the local variable within the initialize function or so I thought)